Why does llama 3.2 8B base model seem to have a chat instruction template?
I have downloaded the Q8 versions of:

https://huggingface.co/QuantFactory/Llama-3.2-1B-GGUF
https://huggingface.co/QuantFactory/Llama-3.2-3B-GGUF
https://huggingface.co/QuantFactory/Llama-3.2-3B-Instruct-GGUF

I have tried launching them with llama.cpp:
./llama-server --host 0.0.0.0 -m models/Llama-3.2-1B.Q8_0.gguf
./llama-server --host 0.0.0.0 -m models/Llama-3.2-3B.Q8_0.gguf -c 4096
./llama-server --host 0.0.0.0 -m models/Llama-3.2-3B-Instruct.Q8_0.gguf -c 4096

I noticed the following information was printed when I launch the Llama-3.2-3B.Q8_0.gguf model:
main: chat template, built_in: 1, chat_example: '<|im_start|>system
You are a helpful assistant<|im_end|>
<|im_start|>user
Hello<|im_end|>
<|im_start|>assistant
Hi there<|im_end|>
<|im_start|>user
How are you?<|im_end|>
<|im_start|>assistant

I am confused about this. It does not happen for the 1B base model. A similar thing is printed for models/Llama-3.2-3B-Instruct.Q8_0.gguf but that makes sense.
Why is this being printed? Is this model incorrectly configured to be a chat model?
